# Geometry Nodes - Point Instance Boolean

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, scatter-objects-addon

I want to create a scatter-like forest pack in Blender. How can I create the "Edge Trim" feature available in 3ds Max (explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfqkirzEGXs)) with Blender?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your current node tree look like? What specifically caused your previous attempts to solve the problem to fail?

Comment: there are several ways possible which of course depend on what you did so far. e.g. boolean modifier, or mesh boolean, or proximity node or raycast...so if you don't show us your node tree, this is more a philosophic question than a specific question.

Comment: Agreed .. we need some indication of what  your scattering mechanism is, already. and where we can intervene.

Comment: I shared my node setup now.

Comment: you could see if the bounding box is over the mesh or you could realize the instances that are close to the path and delete the parts of that mesh that are over it.